# Steamapi Dns calls without steam being open

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-10, wireshark

So , after some time I re-opened wireshark to update it and I saw something pretty strange, now I'm really not sure what this is and that might just be a basic thing but I can't seem to understand why my computer communicates with the steam api on a DNS protocol even if there are absolutely no instances of steam running right now, here is a screenshot:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The column that you refer to which has the "80" and "96" values is "length", not "port".

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist just saw that now sorry, my bad...

Comment: Which OS is this happening on?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is apparently on Windows, here is one way of tracking down which process initiated the DNS lookup (assuming it was done using the normal Windows APIs) using the built-in audit facility:

- Open *Event Viewer* (eventvwr.exe)
- Navigate to *Applications and Services Logs* -> *Microsoft* -> *Windows* -> *DNS Client Events* -> *Operational*
- If the log is empty, you will have to first enable the log by choosing *Enable log* in the right-hand pane.
- Browse/search the log until you find what you are looking for (wait/refresh as necessary if the log was disabled)
- When you have found a recent log event that matches the query that you are looking for, go to *Details* -> *System* -> *Execution* -> *ProcessID*
- Now look up this PID in for example *Task Manager*
  (Obviously this mapping of PID -> process information needs to be done relatively shortly after the log entry was created - the same process needs to be running still)